# Modifying readChar() in R

Tags: r, chinese-locale

I want to read a file with Chinese characters using `readChar()`. I could use readLines() and specify `encoding = "UTF-8"`, but using `readChar()` would make things much easier.

Is there any way I can modify the function `readChar()`, or create a new function, to allow for encoding to be specified?